# Why can I access a component variable only from outside the component?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have made a variation of an example app from an Angular book.
A working example (in development mode) can be found here: http://ng-ex.watchduck.net/#/21
The source code can also be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/watchduck/angular_examples/tree/master/src/app/m021).

The component `log` has the variable `autoRefresh`. (see [here](https://github.com/watchduck/angular_examples/blob/master/src/app/m021/log/log.component.ts#L15))

```js
export class LogComponent implements OnInit {

  autoRefresh: boolean = false;

  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }  

  ngOnInit() {
    this.changeDetector.detach();  // Here is the problem.
  }

  render() {
    this.changeDetector.reattach();
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
    this.changeDetector.detach();
  }
  start() { this.autoRefresh = true; }
  stop() { this.autoRefresh = false; }

}
```

I would like to use it in the component (in the green box) to show the current status, and to disable two buttons based on it. (see [here](https://github.com/watchduck/angular_examples/blob/master/src/app/m021/log/log.component.html#L4-L12)) But that does not work. No initial value is shown, and then it just sticks with the first value.

```html
<button (click)="start()" [disabled]="autoRefresh">start</button>
<button (click)="stop()" [disabled]="!autoRefresh">stop</button>
```

But when I place the buttons outside of the component it works. (see [here](https://github.com/watchduck/angular_examples/blob/master/src/app/m021/main/main.component.html#L15-L23))

```html
<button (click)="viewer.start()" [disabled]="viewer.autoRefresh">start</button>
<button (click)="viewer.stop()" [disabled]="!viewer.autoRefresh">stop</button>

<app-log #viewer [logs]="logs"></app-log>
```

[image]

This is quite counter-intuitive, right? What is going wrong here?

---

**Edit:** The problem goes away, when I remove `this.changeDetector.detach();` from `ngOnInit`.
But of course having it there is the point of this exercise.

To clarify: If the `disabled` attributes were removed, the start and stop button in the component would work fine. What fails is binding the variable `autoRefresh` to the `disabled` attributes (as well as using it with `ngSwitch` or just showing it with `{{autoRefresh}}`).

Comment: Please paste actual code not links to code or images

Comment: it works because you are getting access to the component instance via the `#viewer` template variable. The ref points to the component thats rendered. At the end its just an object that exists in memory with some metadata, and your methods. https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#how-angular-assigns-values-to-template-variables

Comment: Are you using onpush change detection strat?

Comment: @hawks My question is why it does _not_ work inside the component. @Antoniossss
No, I am using `ChangeDetectorRef`.

Comment: @Watchduck sorry. But I dont understand why you using the cdref. Most probably you are not attaching the view to cdref when clicking start and stop methods so angular can run the change detection and update the dom

Comment: The chapter in the book is about `ChangeDetectorRef`, and the example may be a bit artificial. The `detach()` in `ngOnInit()` and in `render()` is what the author is explaining. The fact that it works from outside the component shows, that this is not just broken. One could be satisfied with that - and the author is. I would just like to understand, why it works from outside the component, but not within.

Comment: Due to lack of change detection, bound value is undefined (yes, aplying initial binding value is a chage as well). Since it is falsy, both buttons are NOT disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you have omitted - before edit - the most important part of the code which is ngoninit in your case....

When you do 'detach'you are simply excludiong current instance of component from angulars change detection cycle.
Because od that, you dont see the effects of setting value of 'autorefresh' as angular doesnt bother to reflect that change.

You effectively almost use onPush detrction strategy by detaching yourself from thr change detector.

When you are placing your buttons outside of the component, the host componemt IS in the change detection cycle therefore you ca see that ui reflects that change.

To verify this, detach the parent component from the change detection ref and you will see exactly the same results

Comment: Given that `autoRefresh` is initially set to _false_, I am still surprised that this is not the initial value I see on the page. Instead the variable does not seem to exist.

Comment: But what is the actual outcome? Both buttons are enabled? False is the initial value.

Comment: I would have expected the stop button inside the component to be initially disabled, just like the one outside. (And then to remain disabled, because changes are not detected.)

Comment: But again, what is the outcome?

Comment: Well ... what you see on the image or on the page: Outside the component the _stop_ button is grayed out (and the text is "Auto refresh is off."). Inside the component both buttons are active (and the text is "Auto refresh is .").